# What is the R equivalent of SQL "SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY c1, c2"?

Tags: sql, r, data.table, aggregate

I want to reduce my data frame (**EDIT:** in a cpu-efficient way) to rows with unique values of the pair c3, c4, while keeping all columns. In other words I want to transform my data frame

```
> df <- data.frame(c1=seq(7), c2=seq(4, 10), c3=c("A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A"), c4=c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1))
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  4  A  1
2  2  5  B  2
3  3  6  B  3
4  4  7  C  3
5  5  8  B  2
6  6  9  A  2
7  7 10  A  1
```

to the data frame

```
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  4  A  1
2  2  5  B  2
3  3  6  B  3
4  4  7  C  3
6  6  9  A  2
```

where the values of c1 and c2 could be any value which occurs for a unique pair of c3, c4. Also the order of the resulting data frame is not of importance.

**EDIT:** My data frame has around 250 000 rows and 12 columns and should be grouped by 2 columns – therefore **I need a CPU-efficient solution**.

### Working but unsatisfactory alternative

I solved this problem with

```
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf("Select * from df Group By c3, c4")
```

but in order to speed up and parallelize my program I have to eliminate the calls to sqldf.

**EDIT:** Currently the sqldf solution clocks at 3.5 seconds. I consider this a decent time. The problem is that I cannot start various queries in parallel therefore I am searching for an alternative way.

### Not working attempts

#### duplicate()

```
> df[duplicated(df, by=c("c3", "c4")),]
[1] c1 c2 c3 c4
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

selects duplicate rows and does not select rows where only columns c3 and c4 are duplicates.

#### aggregate()

```
> aggregate(df, by=list(df$c3, df$c4))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

aggregate requires a function applied to all lines with the same values of c3 and c4

#### data.table's by

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(df)
> dt[,list(c1, c2) ,by=list(c3, c4)]
    c3 c4 c1 c2
1:  A  1  1  4
2:  A  1  7 10
3:  B  2  2  5
4:  B  2  5  8
5:  B  3  3  6
6:  C  3  4  7
7:  A  2  6  9
```

does not kick out the rows which have non-unique values of c3 and c4, whereas

```
> dt[ ,length(c1), by=list(c3, c4)]
   c3 c4 V1
1:  A  1  2
2:  B  2  2
3:  B  3  1
4:  C  3  1
5:  A  2  1
```

does discard the values of c1 and c2 and reduces them to one dimension as specified with the passed function `length`.

Comment: You can add indexes to speed up the SQL.  See the sqldf home page.

Comment: As evident from your comments in some answers, the high runtime is a result of using factors. Some of your columns have >100000 factors which is diabolical! You might want to use `stringsAsFactors=F` as suggested by @jlhoward while importing the dataset (assuming you are using `read.csv`). Otherwise, you might want to use `dt[] <- lapply(dt, as.character)`. In this case, you will need to convert your numerical columns again as they will be converted too. You can use `mutate_if` from `dplyr` to convert only factor columns (see the documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df),c3,c4)   # convert df to a data.table and set the keys.
df[,.SD[1],by=list(c3,c4)]
#    c3 c4 c1 c2
# 1:  A  1  1  4
# 2:  A  2  6  9
# 3:  B  2  2  5
# 4:  B  3  3  6
# 5:  C  3  4  7
```

The SQL you propose seems to extract the first row having a given combination of (c3,c4) - I assume that's what you want.

---

**EDIT**: Response to OP's comments.

The result you cite seems really odd. The benchmarks below, on a dataset with 12 columns and 2.5e5 rows, show that the data.table solution runs in about 25 **milliseconds** without setting keys, and in about 7 milliseconds with keys set.

```
set.seed(1)  # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(c3=sample(LETTERS[1:10],2.5e5,replace=TRUE),
                 c4=sample(1:10,2.5e5,replace=TRUE),
                 matrix(sample(1:10,2.5e6,replace=TRUE),nc=10))
library(data.table)
DT.1 <- as.data.table(df)
DT.2 <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(DT.2,c3,c4)
f.nokeys <- function() DT.1[,.SD[1],by=list(c3,c4)]
f.keys   <- function() DT.2[,.SD[1],by=list(c3,c4)]
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f.nokeys(),f.keys(),times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  f.nokeys() 23.73651 24.193129 24.609179 25.747767 26.181288    10
#    f.keys()  5.93546  6.207299  6.395041  6.733803  6.900224    10
```

In what ways is your dataset different from this one??

Comment: The data.table solution works, but runs for 58 seconds on my machine with a table of ~250k rows and 12 columns, which is to be grouped by two columns. Is there a way to speed it up significantly? The sqldf query clocks at a median 3.5 seconds (n=10)

Comment: Setting the keys first might speed things up. I've edited the answer.

Comment: it sped up, although the procedure takes as long as 42s on my machine (mean, n=3).

Comment: This does not make sense. See the benchmarks added to the answer.

Comment: @jups42, what's your version of data.table? Also have you tried what I wrote under comments?

Comment: @jlhoward

    >str(data)
    'data.frame': 245714 obs. of  12 variables:  
    $ c1: int  
    $ c2            : Factor w/ 179906 levels  
    $ c3        : num  
    $ c4       : num  
 $ c5         : Factor w/ 147582 levels  
    $ c6     : Factor w/ 586 levels  
    $ c7        : Factor w/ 10 levels  
    $ c8         : Factor w/ 1 level  
    $ c9            : Factor w/ 2562 levels  
    $ c10        : Factor w/ 5299 levels  
    $ c10          : Factor w/ 3 levels  
    $ c11      : int

Comment: @jlhoward One difference is that I have 12 columns. Maybe the data types influence the runtime differences? I posted the output of str() in the comment above.

Comment: It may be because your columns are factors. Perhaps @Arun will weight in?? How do you get the data into R? With `read.csv(...)` perhaps? If so, add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the call to `read.csv(...)` and try again. It's hard to see how you would ever need a factor with 180,000 levels.

Answer (score 2):

Drawback (maybe): All solutions sort the result by group variables.

## Using `aggregate`

Solution mentioned by Martin: `aggregate(. ~ c3 + c4, df, head, 1)`

My old solution:

```
> aggregate(df,by=list(df$c3,df$c4),FUN=head,1)
  Group.1 Group.2 c1 c2 c3 c4
1       A       1  1  4  A  1
2       A       2  6  9  A  2
3       B       2  2  5  B  2
4       B       3  3  6  B  3
5       C       3  4  7  C  3
> aggregate(df,by=list(df$c3,df$c4),FUN=head,1)[,-(1:2)]
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  4  A  1
2  6  9  A  2
3  2  5  B  2
4  3  6  B  3
5  4  7  C  3
```

## Using `ddply`

```
> require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
> ddply(df, ~ c3 + c4, head, 1)
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  4  A  1
2  6  9  A  2
3  2  5  B  2
4  3  6  B  3
5  4  7  C  3
```

Comment: Alternative `aggregate()` using formula notation `aggregate(. ~ c3 + c4, df, head, 1)`.

Comment: The aggregate() solution works greatly, but has runs for 47 seconds on my machine with a table of ~250k rows and 12 columns, which is to be grouped by two columns. 
The plyr solution causes my machine to be out of memory. 
Is there a way to speed them up given that the sqldf solution runs for a median 3.5s (n=10)?

Comment: @jups42 in the formula variation of aggregate, use `c(rowidx=seq_len(nrow(df))` in place of `.`, and subset the original data frame?

Answer (score 2):

Some dplyr options:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, c3, c4) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
group_by(df, c3, c4) %>% slice(1)
group_by(df, c3, c4) %>% do(head(.,1))
group_by(df, c3, c4) %>% summarise_each(funs(first))
group_by(df, c3, c4) %>% summarise_each(funs(.[1]))
group_by(df, c3, c4) %>% summarise_each(funs(head(.,1)))
group_by(df, c3, c4) %>% distinct()
```

Here's a dplyr-only benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(99)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(500, 25e4*12, replace = TRUE), ncol = 12))
dim(df)

microbenchmark(
  f1 = {group_by(df, X1, X2) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)},
  f2 = {group_by(df, X1, X2) %>% summarise_each(funs(first))},
  f3 = {group_by(df, X1, X2) %>% summarise_each(funs(.[1]))},
  f4 = {group_by(df, X1, X2) %>% summarise_each(funs(head(., 1)))},
  f5 = {group_by(df, X1, X2) %>% distinct()},
  times = 10
)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr   min    lq median    uq   max neval
   f1   498   505    509   527   615    10
   f2   726   766    794   815   823    10
   f3  1485  1504   1545  1571  1639    10
   f4 25170 25668  26027 26188 26406    10
   f5   618   622    631   653   675    10
```

I excluded the version with `do(head(.,1))` since it's just not a very good option and takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `interaction` and `duplicated`:

```
subset(df, !duplicated(interaction(c3, c4)))
#   c1 c2 c3 c4
# 1  1  4  A  1
# 2  2  5  B  2
# 3  3  6  B  3
# 4  4  7  C  3
# 6  6  9  A  2
```

Comment: this solution may work for small data sizes but is unpractical for my problem (after my edit): In a test with my data (12 columns, group by 2, 250k rows) I suspended R after having run for minutes.